# How can I get top level module name python -m was called with?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Consider the following python sample module:

```
./
├─pyproject.toml
├─src/
│ └─mymodule/
│   ├─entrypoint.py
│   ├─module.py
```

With content:

```
mkdir -p src/mymodule/

cat >pyproject.toml <<EOF
[project]
name = "mymodule"
EOF

cat >src/mymodule/entrypoint.py <<EOF
from . import module
EOF

cat >src/mymodule/module.py <<EOF
import sys
from pathlib import Path

# I want to get "mymodule.entrypoint" here.
print(__loader__.__dict__)
print(sys.argv)
print(__name__)
print(sys.path)
print(str(Path(sys.argv[0]).relative_to(Path(sys.path[0]))).replace(".py", "").replace("/", "."))
EOF
```

I am executing:

```
pip install -e .
python -m mymodule.entrypoint
```

How can I get the top level module string `"mymodule.entrypoint"` that python was called with from within `module.py`?

I tried:

- `sys.argv` is `/the/full/path/to/src/mymodule/entrypoint.py`
- `__loader__.name` is `mymodule.module`
- `__name__` is `mymodule.module`
- searching stackoverflow and web
- The `str(Path(sys.argv[0]).relative_to(Path(sys.path[0]))).repalce(".py", "").replace("/", ".")` looks terrible and does not give the exact result.